# How to create array list that one of it parameters will equals parameter from another array

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have API call with weather.
On Response, I'm getting WeatherResponse that contain array lists of Daily temp, hourly temp and minutely temp.
In other side, I have RecyclerView that's showing all day from daily array.
When I click on some day on RecyclerView , I need to expand the clicked item and show the all hours from same day.
I have created view that contain TextView(Day from daily) and RecyclerView(Hours) that will contain hours of the clicked day.
In my Days rv adapter I make interface that listening to click on day and implement it in main activity.
The interface transfer position of click day and daily array list.
I create one more adapter for Hourly rv that inside daily rv.
So, how can I create list of hours from the selected day ?

Here is the WeatherResponse

```
public class WeatherResponse extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("minutely")
    @Expose
    private List<Minutely> minutely = null;
    @SerializedName("hourly")
    @Expose
    private List<Hourly> hourly = null;
    @SerializedName("daily")
    @Expose
    private List<Daily> daily = null;

    public WeatherResponse() {
    }

    @Bindable
    public List<Minutely> getMinutely() {
        return minutely;
    }

    public void setMinutely(List<Minutely> minutely) {
        this.minutely = minutely;
    }

    @Bindable
    public List<Hourly> getHourly() {
        return hourly;
    }

    public void setHourly(List<Hourly> hourly) {
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hourly);
        this.hourly = hourly;
    }

    @Bindable
    public List<Daily> getDaily() {
        return daily;
    }

    public void setDaily(List<Daily> daily) {
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.daily);
        this.daily = daily;
    }

}
```

And Hourly Model

```
public class Hourly implements Parcelable
{

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private int dt;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private double temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    @Expose
    private double feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private int pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private int humidity;
    @SerializedName("dew_point")
    @Expose
    private double dewPoint;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private int clouds;
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    @Expose
    private double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    @Expose
    private int windDeg;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("rain")
    @Expose
    private Rain rain;
}
```

And Daily Model

```
public class Daily extends BaseObservable implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private int dt;
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    @Expose
    private int sunrise;
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    @Expose
    private int sunset;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private Temp temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    @Expose
    private FeelsLike feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private int pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private int humidity;
    @SerializedName("dew_point")
    @Expose
    private double dewPoint;
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    @Expose
    private double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    @Expose
    private int windDeg;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private int clouds;
    @SerializedName("rain")
    @Expose
    private double rain;
    @SerializedName("uvi")
    @Expose
    private double uvi;
}
```

Daily adapter bind function:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DayViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Daily daily = dailies.get(position);
        holder.dayItemViewBinding.setDaily(daily);
        holder.dayItemViewBinding.getRoot().setTag(position);

        holder.dayItemViewBinding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
                if (callback != null){
                    callback.onDayItemClick(position, daily);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can set another RecyclerView in item of your MainRecyclerView , and create another adapter and set it in your onBindViewHolder,, i think it's simply way

Comment: You are understand my question , I set a new event but got to create list of hours of the selected days ?

Comment: add isSelected to your model,  set visibility gone if its not selected, on click listener set it selected true and notifyDataSetchanged

Comment: are you asking for showing them or what???
can i see your viewHolder to understood what is your problem?
because i think you haven't any problem to got daily and hourly arrays and you got them from server

Comment: The problem is not to show the hours array list , but to create it.

Comment: What format should the hours be in?  Just an integer like (0, 1, 2, 3...) or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
private void fillHoursRecyclerView(Daily daily) {
        selectedDay = new TimeUtils();
        hourToShow = new TimeUtils();
        selectedDay.getReadableDay(daily.getDt());
        ArrayList hourlies = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < weatherResponseViewModel.getHourlyWeatherData().getValue().size(); i++) {
            if (hourToShow.getReadableDay(weatherResponseViewModel.getHourlyWeatherData().getValue().get(i).getDt()).equals(selectedDay.getReadableDay(daily.getDt()))) {
                hourlies.add(weatherResponseViewModel.getHourlyWeatherData().getValue().get(i));
            }
        }

        hoursRvAdapter = new HoursRvAdapter(getApplicationContext(), hourlies);
        hoursRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hoursRecyclerView);
        hoursRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        hoursRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        hoursRecyclerView.setAdapter(hoursRvAdapter);
        hoursRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hoursRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

public class TimeUtils {

    private String readableDay;

    public String getReadableDay(int dt) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            readableDay = Instant.ofEpochSecond(dt)
                    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jerusalem"))
                    .getDayOfWeek()
                    .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.US);
        }
        return readableDay;
    }

}
```